# Как объединить данные, хранящиеся в виде «ключ-значение»?

Tags: mysql

Есть вот такие таблицы, данные которых мне нужно объединить на основании одного параметра (subscriber_id и ID), там где и один и второй равен '2'

[image: Первая таблица]
[image: Вторая таблица]

Делаю запрос..

```
SELECT wp_mymail_subscriber_fields.meta_value,
wp_mymail_subscribers.email FROM wp_mymail_subscribers,
wp_mymail_subscriber_fields, wp_mymail_subscriber_meta
WHERE wp_mymail_subscriber_meta.subscriber_id = '2'
AND wp_mymail_subscriber_fields.subscriber_id = '2'
AND wp_mymail_subscribers.ID = '2'
group by `meta_value`
ORDER BY `meta_value` DESC
```

В ответ получаю

[image: ответ]

А вот как сделать, чтобы meta_value, где meta_key = 'firstname' выводилась как fname, а meta_value, где meta_key = 'lastname' как lname ?

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос, так чтобы он был более абстрактным и полезен другим, а не был в стиле "напишите код за меня для этого конкретного случая".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, так:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b53fe/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table s (id int, email text);
create table m (sid int, mkey text, mvalue text);

insert into s values
  (1, 'odin@domain.tld'),
  (2, 'dva@domain.tld');

insert into m values
  (1, 'firstname', 'вася'),
  (1, 'lastname', 'пупкин'),
  (2, 'firstname', 'маня'),
  (2, 'lastname', 'зорькина');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select s.email, m1.mvalue as firstname, m2.mvalue as lastname
from s
left join m m1
  on m1.sid = s.id and m1.mkey = 'firstname'
left join m m2
  on m2.sid = s.id and m2.mkey = 'lastname'
where s.id = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b53fe/1/0)**:

```
|          email | mvalue |   mvalue |
|----------------|--------|----------|
| dva@domain.tld |   маня | зорькина |
```